# Relationship between akka Actor and Java Thread?

Tags: java, akka, actor

I am trying to get my head around Akka and onething which I am not able to visualize is the relation between Java Threads to Akka Actors

- is it `1:1`?
- is it `1:many`?

I am confused with it now

Comment: Did you read the section on dispatchers in the documentation? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/scala/dispatchers.html

Comment: I guess it is many-to-many. Any actor may be served by any thread and vice-versa.

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actors.html

Answer (score 3):

Akka actors (usually) do not have a fixed thread assigned to them. Threads are assigned to messages.

The dispatcher assigns threads to messages which are polled from the mailbox. He decides when each actor can start processing a message. When the actor has an empty mailbox, he owns no thread. The number of threads per dispatcher is configurable.

Though there is a dispatcher called the "pinned dispatcher", which gives one fixed thread to each actor, it is rarely used.